# Interface with friend operator<<: why can't it link?

Tags: c++, friend-function, linker-errors

I have created a small interface for objects that can be represented in text mode using the `operator<<` like so:

```
// ICliObject.h

class ICliObject
{
public:

    ~ICliObject() = default;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& p_stream, const ICliObject& p_cliUiObject);


protected:
    virtual void print(std::ostream& p_stream) const = 0;

};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& p_stream, const ICliObject& p_cliUiObject)
{
    p_cliUiObject.print(p_stream);

    return p_stream;
}
```

When I inherit from this interface and try to build, the compilation works but I get the following linking error: `In blablabla.cpp: multiple definition of operator<<(std::ostream& p_stream, const ICliObject& p_cliUiObject)`

In all derived classes, I have took care of not re-defining/declaring the operator. The only way I can solve my problem is in inlining the operator in `ICliObject.h`. *What is going on?*

Note: I use GCC on Ubuntu.

Comment: Either mark the function definition in the header with `inline` keyword, or move it to some source file.

Comment: You need to add `inline` to the function definition.

Comment: Copy your linker error and search for it in SO. You might find one or more questions on the subject.

Comment: I have, but it's mostly people that have forgotten not to re-define/declare. Also, I have found the inline solution, I just want to know why it is neccessary here. Thanks

Comment: It seems to me the linker should know what to do here even without inlining.

Comment: Telling the linker not to complain that the same symbol is defined in multiple translation units is the reason the `inline` keyword exists.

Comment: @MilesBudnek: I'd argue that it's the reason the `inline` keyword _still_ exists; it doesn't seem likely to have been its original primary job, given the name.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Please, do not answer questions in the comments section. Thank you.

Comment: @BobMorane: "Don't put [non-inline] function definitions into header files" - have you ever heard about this basic rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `friend` or with `operator<<` or with inheritance.

Like *any* function (or object) defined at namespace scope, if you do so multiple times in your program (including by having it in a header file that you `#include` in multiple translation units), you will get this error.

And, like in all those other cases, the solution is to either move the implementation to a "source file", or stick the `inline` keyword on it (which you already suggested, but it's literally the solution so I don't know why it's not acceptable).

Comment: Another possible solution would be to define the function inside the class definition  (because that makes it implicitly `inline`)

Comment: So the definition I added outside the class (but in the same header file) for `operator<<` made it defined multiple times across the program, which caused the linking error. I get it, thanks.